# What happens if I specify OneToMany relationship only from one side in flask-sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a OneToMany relationship between 2 entities in flask. I also specified the relationship only on one side. I am unsure what the difference is between the following:

```
class CustomJob(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "custom_job"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    country_from = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('country.id'))

class Country(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "country"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    custom_jobs = db.relationship('CustomJob', backref="country", lazy=False)
```

Or just specify the foreign key on master entity:

```
class CustomJob(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "custom_job"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    country_from = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('country.id'))
```

will is there performance difference between the two ?

Answer (score 0):

The brilliance behind an ORM like SQLAlchemy is that it can detect relationships between models based on [foreign key constraints](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/basic_relationships.html). So once you've declared your foreign key on the `custom_job` table, the relationship is configured in the database.

Mapping that relationship to your python objects is another useful part of ORM's. Here, you are doing that with `db.relationship`. By specifying `backref`, you are essentially telling the ORM to make the relationship available on the other object.

*Let me explain more explicitly using the code provided in your Q:*

```py
class Country(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'country'
    ...
    custom_jobs = db.relationship('CustomJob', backref='custom_job', lazy=False)
    ...
```

The `Country` model you've defined will map all associated rows from the `custom_job` table through the attribute `Country.custom_jobs`.

This relationship will propagate to the `CustomJob` model and allow you to access the associated rows from the `country` table through an attribute created by the `backref` parameter --> here `CustomJob.custom_job`.

> *I assume this is an error and that you intended to use `backref="country"`
>
> In this case, access associated objects instead with `CustomJob.country`*