# How to combine and match 2 tables in Flask

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-restful, flask-login

The id is associated with the postID. How can I get the contact information and comment information of that id when I enter the id(/postComments/id)?
*I'm getting an internal error...*

```
class posts(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "posts"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(100))
    postName = db.Column(db.String(100))
    postDescription = db.Column(db.String(500))
    postLike = db.Column(db.Integer)

class postComment(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "postComment"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    postID = db.Column(db.Integer)
    senderName = db.Column(db.String(20))
    commentPost = db.Column(db.String(300))



@app.route('/postComments/<id>',methods=['GET'])
def get_comment_post(id):
    userList = posts.query\
    .join(postComment, posts.id == postComment.postID)\
    .add_columns(posts.id, posts.name, posts.postDescription, postComment.commentPost, postComment.senderName)\
    .filter(posts.id == id)
```

Answer (score 1):

Modify your models (and perform migrations) to allow reference for foreign keys:

```py
class postComment(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "postComment"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    postID = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("posts.id")) #  <--- Set to Foreign Key
    senderName = db.Column(db.String(20))
    commentPost = db.Column(db.String(300))

    # Establish relationship
    post = db.Relationship("posts", backref="postComment") #  <--- backref makes this relationship available in the other class


# This should get simpler...
@app.route('/postComments/<id>',methods=['GET'])
def get_comment_post(id):
    # Get the comment based on id
    my_comment = postComment.query.get(id)
    
    # Get the post associated with that comment
    my_post = my_comment.post

    # It looks like you're doing an intricate data transformation.
    # Do that here...
    # Also, for debugging, consider using the following print statements
    print(my_comment.__dict__)
    print(my_post.__dict__)
```

Consider reading this [slightly more detailed explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65374495/10521959) for establishing relationships.

Comment: I am having a problem with the data conversion there. I have comment information (sender, comment ...). I'm trying to get these comments and the post that this comment belongs to but failed :(

Comment: What do you get when trying `print(my_post.__dict__)`? @BahadırSeyfi

Comment: my_comment = postComment.get(id)
AttributeError: type object 'postComment' has no attribute 'get'
127.0.0.1 - - [24/Dec/2020 12:58:59] "GET /postComments/2 HTTP/1.1" 500 -                                   if you read this maybe more understandable : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65409817/how-can-i-get-information-from-2-separate-tables-with-a-single-request-in-flask

Comment: _My bad!_ I updated it to `postComment.query.get(id)`

Comment: my_post = postComment.post
AttributeError: type object 'postComment' has no attribute 'post'    :( I don't understand

Comment: My apologies, the answer I posted had errors. I fixed again for you --> `my_post = my_comment.post` @BahadırSeyfi